# "Ad shetichleh" or "ad shetikaleh"?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, chanuka

What is the correct ניקוד (and concomitant translation) of the word שתכלה in the phrase

> [עד שתכלה רגל מן השוק](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%91_%D7%90#.D7.9E.D7.92.D7.9F_.D7.90.D7.91.D7.A8.D7.94.D7.9D)

?

Is it תִכְלֶה, which would [be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_grammar#Binyan_pa.27al) [קל](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA#.D7.91.D7.A0.D7.99.D7.99.D7.9F_.D7.A7.D7.9C) or תִכָּלֶה, which would [be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_grammar#Binyan_nif.27al) [נפעל](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA#.D7.91.D7.A0.D7.99.D7.99.D7.9F_.D7.A0.D7.A4.D7.A2.D7.9C)?

Does this difference also determine which of [two similar שרשים](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43656&st=&pgnum=167) is in effect?

(I linked to the Shulchan Aruch for ease of finding on the page even though it is quoting from a much earlier source.)

Comment: Would this distinction have halachic ramifications? Maybe the former is more like "until everyone goes home" and the latter is more like "until everyone is sent home," and the latter only starts when it's no longer safe or practical to be out (later than the former standard)?

Comment: I don't think it would have legal ramifications since 1) mostly everyone holds that these days this timeframe is an absolute, independent of people's habits and 2) that would be hard to justify in light of רבה בר בר חנה's opinion in the גמרא.

Comment: תכלה שנה וקללותיה is tichley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Tichle* (*kal*), "will cease", makes sense to me, as does the *pual t'chule*, "will be terminated", as in "*vaychulu hashamayim*". (I suspect it's *tichle*.) I don't know of any word *tikale* (*nif'al*), though that doesn't, of course, mean one doesn't exist.